# Conversion from iOS 13 UIDatepicker to iOS 14 UIDatepicker

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker, ios14

I am currently trying to figure out how to change in code from iOS 13 UIDatePicker to the iOS 14 version with (`.wheels`). Below you will find a screen shot of the app with the non-functioning date picker and screenshot of the code.

Unfortunately while I am able to understand Swift I am not conversant enough to know where and what changes need to be made so the code will work. I have tried some of the other solutions on here but to no avail. So if anyone could help me that would be great.

I believe I need to change the code for the `dateBtnAction`, but I have no clue where the new iOS 14 code would go.

```
@IBAction func datePickerAction(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.amSymbol = "am"
    formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
    // formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    // formatter.dateStyle  = .medium
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
    dateBtn.setTitle(dateString, for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func dateBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    popupView(forView: datePickerContainerView, viewHeight: 300)
}
```

| Code snippet | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image: View Controller snippet of UIDatePicker] | [image: Image of UIDatePicker on iPhone] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this code in you `viewDidLoad` or wherever you setup your datePicker:

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
   yourDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
   //yourDatePicker can be in code or IBOutlet

}
```

according to the documentation these are the styles available (iOS 13.4):

> **Styles**
>
> **case automatic**
> A style indicating that the system picks the concrete style based on the current platform and date picker mode.
>
> **case compact**
> A style indicating that the date picker displays as a label that when tapped displays a calendar-style editor.
>
> **case inline**
> A style indicating that the date pickers displays as an inline, editable field.
>
> **case wheels**
> A style indicating that the date picker displays as a wheel picker.